# PhpStorm - html classes suggestions

Tags: html, css, phpstorm

Is it possible to suggest css classes from my css files in PhpStorm when coding html templates? In Netbenas, this was pretty awesome function and I would like to use this in PhpStorm too.

[image]

Comment: This should work by default. How's your project set up? Are both HTML and CSS files part of the same project?

Comment: How many `.css` files do you have in your project and how bug they are (in total)? The stuff works fine out of the box (as @Rahul have said in his answer) but may fail if you have too many .css files. Try it first in some simple project. Also ... since you are using templates ... try removing all *most likely* unnecessary stuff (e.g. just leave `<span>` content).

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. PhpStrom is very smart it automatically includes every single css class which we written in your stylesheets, Just simply add your any CSS classes in your stylesheets,

Eg: You have style.css and now you want to use a class `my-class{background-color: green;}` if your CSS is included in your project then it will automatically show up in your HTML code when you write it.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yes, CSS files are part of my project. http://snag.gy/Tyl2w.jpg .Phpstorm find CSS (or LESS) files by default or they need to be registred somewhere? Thanks.

Comment: As I can see these files are part of your project but your CSS file is not included in your test.html.

You need to include CSS file as well.

Comment: use 
<link href="[Path]/css/t/combined.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
in your head section of test.html

Comment: Doesn't work. Anyway, I'm using template engine and I don't need dummy <link> because I want to use different css/js on production. It should work in another way. Netbeans search all css files inside project and suggest all classes by default. I would like to have same behaviour in Phpstorm.

Answer (score 1):

Also consider to exclude `<style>` tags inside your template files. I was desperately googling until I found [this thread in jetbrains support forums](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207056535-PHPStorm-6-CSS-Class-completion-not-working-?page=1#community_comment_207430909)

I really had some included styles in template and this was the problem.